# Partial Regex Extraction from URL

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

I had asked a question , many thanks for all the help. 
I have a URL Like this.

> /Hello/World/special/Case/2016/07/01/offer-015155.html

I need only "`2016/07/01/offer-015155`" this part and this dynamically changes each time. Could you help?

- I tried `"(.*?)" , "\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/offer-\d+."` but did not help.

When I run it says, not found . :(

Comment: You should escape the delimiters: `\d{4}\/\d\d\/\d\d\/offer-\d+`

Comment: [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vY5mS2/1) is your friend. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva : I tried exactly that...did not work

Comment: It is a little bit different than the one quoted in your post, as the delimiters are escaped. Here is [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH1uZ6/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want extract the part of an URL it will be quite enough to use something very simple like `(.+)`

Demo:

[image: RegExp Tester]

Example Regular Expression configuration (mind "Field to Check" bit)

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](http://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: Thank you Dmitiri. You are just awesome as usual. But see I have this thing here like this.       I have extracted something now, so it would be like this now "/2016/01/07/offer-456789.html". Is there any way, I can "remove" the .html....so that I could use on till the part where I don't have .html. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe change regex to `/Hello/World/special/Case/(.+).html`?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a positive lookbehind combined with a positive lookahead, like this:

```
(?<=\/Hello\/World\/special\/Case\/).*(?=.html)
```

This regex is very explicit but does the job. See this for an explanation of the regex: https://regex101.com/r/vY5mS2/2

EDIT:
Or simply use capture groups (https://regex101.com/r/vY5mS2/5)

```
\/Hello\/World\/special\/Case\/(.*)\.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code also:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}/offer-\\d+)");
        String testString = "/Hello/World/special/Case/2016/07/01/offer-015155.html";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Execution result: `2016/07/01/offer-015155`

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I cant implement this in JMeter tool. Isnt it right?

Comment: Probably you could use just regex in JMeter: (\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}/offer-\\d+)